# EC2 can't retrieve the platform because the AMI was either deleted or made private

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 4 existing AWS EC2 instances that have been running well.

I changed the instance type on all of them at the same time and following the same process.
I went from t3.small to t3.large as well as the EBS type, going from gp2 to gp3.

It worked for 3 instances but 1 is now having this error:

> EC2 can't retrieve the platform because the AMI was either deleted or made private.

I cannot SSH anymore with this instance nor "Connect" to it via the AWS Console, but it's still running well.

I tried reverting to t3.small, and launch the `AWSSupport-TroubleshootSSH` automation script, but none worked.

Any clues on how to fix this besides launching a new instance? Thank you!

Comment: if they are not production running instance, if you can reboot or do stop/start on the instance?

Comment: @samtoddler They are in production, I rebooted them anyway but it did not fix the issue. It looks like the only way would be to launch a new instance and re-attach the EBS, but I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: It might be that, but a long shot seems to me, the other three machines had different base AMI from the problematic instance and the AMI is not available for this fourth machine anymore hence the trouble. So in case you have data on this instance you can still backup that up on another instance by attaching the EBS volume from this instance.